# Is it possible to create a VPC with only a public subnet and NAT for EC2 instances without elastic IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I need to migrate a big cluster of VMs to AWS. Some of these have Public IPs, others only local IPs. Is it possible to create mixed subnetwork of Public and Private IPs within a VPC such that instances with a Public IP access the Internet via an Elastic IP and the Internet Gateway and such that instances that don't have a Public IP go to the Internet over NAT. The local IP instances must be in a single subnetwork such as 192.168.1.0/24.

Is it possible how to do this? and what would be an optimal approach?

Comment: In theory you could update the route table on the instance itself (imho bad idea), but I don't see any reason why not to separate the public and private instances into different subnets. I believe the migration services (AWS Server Migration, AWS Application Migration Service) could help you set up the subnets. Do the all VMs needs to be really on a single subnet?

Comment: Yes, reconfiguration IPs brings a lot of work. I tried to change route to NAT gateway but it didn't work. May be it blocked unathourized traffic or I forgot to check metrics for the new route. So I see only way to add elastic IP to each server and make insfrasructure more expensive or create my own NAT gateway as instance.

Comment: Maybe you could check the AWS Application Migration Service or Server Migration Service. I believe the services could help you to place the VM into the right subnets. You placed a constraint to have a single subnet without saying why, maybe the  there is a way around the constraint

Comment: Yes, of course I will use it. I just prepare and investigate all possible problems.  Thank you!

Comment: I have found working solution for my problem. I have created network /23 so second /24 network is totally under my control. Plobably it will save time for somebody. And such as elastic IP is free hence it is absolutely no problem to have on each server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html), a public subnet has a route to an Internet Gateway. Anything in that subnet that needs to access the Internet will need a public IP (not necessarily an Elastic IP, just a public IP) assigned to it.

> If a subnet's traffic is routed to an internet gateway, the subnet is known as a public subnet.

Similarly, by definition a private subnet is a subnet without an Internet Gateway, which relies on route to a NAT Gateway to access the Internet.

> If a subnet doesn't have a route to the internet gateway, the subnet
> is known as a private subnet.

Per your question, no, there's no way to have a single route table that routes traffic to both an Internet Gateway and a NAT Gateway based on the presence or lack of a public IP address on the source server.